# How to run multiple domain on a JBoss 7 Server

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss6.x

'I want to run multiple domains on a single JBoss7 Server. Is it possible to do that. Please mention the details of the configuration or the idea how to make multiple domain run on a single JBoss 7 server. Thanking You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up multiple alias's (domains) in the standalone/configuration/standalone.xml file, eg...

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="default-host">
    <connector name="http" scheme="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
       <alias name="localhost" />
       <alias name="example.com" />
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

In JBoss AS 6 you can do the same in the /deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml file by adding a Host entry

```
<Host name="host">
    <Alias>example.com</Alias>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
        prefix="processor" suffix=".log" pattern="common"
        directory="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log"/>
    <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve"
        cachedConnectionManagerObjectName="jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager"
        transactionManagerObjectName="jboss:service=TransactionManager">
    </Valve>
</Host>
```